# Symfony2 Custom configuration file

Tags: symfony

When we install symfony 2, installer will ask for values of variables from parameter.yml.dist that are not present in parameter.yml.

Is there a way to create your custom yml and yml.dist file in App/config?

e.g. my.yml will be created while installing and parameters defined in my.yml.dist will be prompted for values at the time of installation.

Comment: ask question proper way

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can create a bunch of custom configuration files. However this is not strictly related to Symfony itself - it's Composer with [Incenteev/ParameterHandler](https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler) "extension".

In your `composer.json` file you'll find following fragment:

```
"extra": {
    "incenteev-parameters": {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "env-map": {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Change it to an array of `incenteev-parameters`:

```
"extra": {
    "incenteev-parameters": [
        {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
            "env-map": {
                ...
            }
        },
        {
            "file": "app/config/my-custom-config.yml",
            "env-map": {
                ...
            }
        }
    ]
}
```